# Private 'My Files' in Drupal Commons

Tags: users, 7, files

I am using the latest release of Drupal Commons and I have Private Files configured and working.

I would like to allow users to upload files to their individual user profile, which only the individual user can view/download after upload. For example, a user may upload 3 files to their profile, but these should be private and not visible or accessible to any other site user.

With Private Files configured, I thought this may be possible via a File field on the user profile, but I have been unable to restrict view to the document owner.

Has anybody acheived a similar result with Commons (with or without addional modules)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before using the [IMCE](https://drupal.org/project/imce) module. The description from the module page says:

> IMCE is an image/file uploader and browser that supports personal directories and quota.

So spot on for your needs.